# How to add a text containing the dynamic current time of the video into video,when finished catching each frame using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to solve it ? I hope to solve it by using a function, no command. I hope someone can help me ?

Comment: Please review the help centre how to ask page.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/1082389/114058. You can use the same drawtext text expression with ffmpeg.